# Copying current Vim buffer into clipboard

Tags: vim, leader

I am trying to copy Vim's buffer to clipboard and I did the following:

`:!cat %|pbcopy` # It works perfectly

Then I tried to map this with the leader key (its my first attempt to map something, so please excuse if something silly is found).

`:map <leader>c :!cat %|pbcopy` # This is not working; vim complains: *Not an Editor command*

Comment: True must have searched better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the pipe

```
:map <leader>c :!cat %\|pbcopy
```

Also consider using nnoremap to stop recursive mappings and ending the command with `<CR>` so the command runs automatically.

```
nnoremap <leader>c :!cat %\|pbcopy<CR>
```

You also might consider using shellescape just incase the file has spaces or other unusual characters

```
nnoremap <leader>c :exec '!cat '.shellescape('%').'\|pbcopy'<CR>
```

Or as Peter Rickner says just use

```
nnoremap <leader>c :w !pbcopy<cr>
```

Comment: Can simplify this to: `nnoremap <leader>c :w !pbcopy<cr>`

Comment: Probably, I should start another question; but if its simple enough: is there a similar solution to copy the yanked lines to clipboard?

Comment: Do you know a solution when you want to use pbcopy for a new file which isn't saved yet? It's useful for me when I do a quick formatting, otherwise I have to use sublime for this.

Comment: @Ismael the pbcopy one doesn't actually use the file in disk at all. vim writes the lines directly to stdin.

Comment: I understand that. In fact, the solution I was looking for is: _:w !pbcopy_ it DOES really saves the buffer without a file behind like _!cat % | pbcopy_ does. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will work on any system, not just Mac:

```
:nmap <leader>c :%y+
```

(I can never remember the difference between the `"+` and `"*` registers.)  OTOH, your method will work if you are on a Mac, using a version of vim that does not have GUI support, such as `/usr/bin/vi`.

```
:help "+
:help :y
```

Comment: The default `/usr/bin/vim` for OS X isn't built w/ `+clipboard`.

Comment: Right:  `/usr/bin/vi` and `/usr/bin/vim` are the same file.  (That is, one is a symlink to the other.)  If you use that file (by either name) then my method will not work.  Are you saying that it is possible to compile vim with +clipboard but no GUI?  Could be true, I have never tried it.